# Where does g++ store compiled sources?

Tags: compiling, g++

I compiled an application with a Makefile and g++ and it turned out, that g++ doesn't have to recompile the whole application again when I modify the Makefile (I changed to paths to the dynamic link libraries).  At that time the application haven't yet compiled successfully, so there was no final executable application available. But g++ didn't compile the whole application again.
Where is this information or compiled sources stored? I didn't see anything neither in /tmp nor in any hidden file within my home dir, nor within the root directory of the application itself. (Maybe I didn't look well enough).

Comment: This is 100% determined by specifics in your makefile.  `make` and `g++` otherwise do everything in the pwd.

Comment: Compiled files would normally end up as `.o` files in the same directory as each C++ source file (_not_ in the root directory of the application). The linker then "links" them together into the final executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC stores what it generates wherever you (or in this case, the Makefile) tell it to (with the `-o` output option). It doesn't do compilation result-caching by itself.

What makes partial recompiles possible is the Makefile itself. It's a set of targets (executable, object files, possibly other things) with what they depend on and rules to generate the target from these dependencies.

`make` looks at everything that needs to be built by evaluating the dependency chains, and rebuilding all the target that either don't exist yet, or have dependencies that are more recent than the target.

For instance, let's say you have this simple Makefile:

```
foo.o: foo.c foo.h
    gcc -o foo.o -c foo.c

foo: foo.o
    gcc -o foo foo.o
```

If you invoke `make foo`, it will look at the Makefile, see that `foo` depends on `foo.o`. So it looks up `foo.o`, and sees that that depends on both `foo.c` and `foo.h`. If `foo.o` is older then either of these two files, or if `foo.o` doesn't exist, it executes the compile line `gcc -o foo.o -c foo.c`, which generates `foo.o`.

If you rerun `make foo` right after that, `foo.o` will be newer than both the C file and the header, so `make` won't re-compile `foo.o`, and skip to linking the final executable (if that's necessary - it might just say that nothing needs to be done).

Answer (score 1):

As the Makefile builds some of the sources look at the individual `g++` commands. The `-o` option shows where the output of the partial compilations is stored.

Make sure to look at the compilation of a C++ source. The last invocation of g++ is probably the link step and then `-o` most often has the binary as argument.